# ARCore hello_ar_java - camera is being accessed by another application

Tags: android, android-camera, augmented-reality

I'm trying to execute the standard 'hello_ar_java' application from ARCore's sample repository via Android Studio. You can find it here: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases

I've been following these instructions: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart

The app runs smoothly on almost every type of device, whether simulated or actual, as long as they're using API 31 or higher. The only exception is a Samsung Galaxy A23 running on API 33. When I initiate the 'hello_ar_java' application on this phone, it launches correctly but the display stays black. Soon after, an alert pops up indicating that another application is utilizing the camera.

[image]

At the time of running the hello_ar_java app, no other camera apps were running to my knowledge, which I checked by checking the current active apps. I cleared the cache of my phone. I also restarted the phone, to no success.

Please let me know if more information is required. The other phones were 3 default Pixel XL emulators, of API 34, 33, and 31 respectively. I also tested it on a Samsung S10 running on API 32, which worked. No duplicate questions were found on the matter, hence my concern.

Technical details about the A23:

- OneUI Version: 5.1
- Android 13
- Know version 3.9